# Two Xcode 8.3.3 errors: Lexical or Preprocessor issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I made my app and it's looking good to me. When I try to build I get the two errors.

[image: picture error 1]

Here is the second error:

[image: picture error 2]

I have no idea. I'm a beginner and I don't really care about mobile ads but I would like to make two versions so I am ignoring it but I can't get past this.

Code for Picture 1 :

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

I get a:

> "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" File not found error in the AppDelegate.m

Second Error that is Parse Issue in Module.Modulemap

```
 umbrella header "GoogleMobileAds.h"
```

The error I get is:

> "Umbrella header 'GoogleMobileAds.h' not found

Any help is appreciated. I worked hard for these errors. I googled and looked around on here and I'm not really understanding the issue.

Comment: How did you integrate the Google frameworks?  Via cocoapods is probably the simplest.

Comment: @Paulw11 i am going to be honest, i know some code, but im not an expert. I use VMWare to code and i was using this : https://codecanyon.net/item/universal-for-ios-full-multipurpose-ios-app/11941410 it's a good start for me i just need help not sure how to fix this. I got all the files.